# Как получать содержимое новых сообщений в telegram канале?

Tags: python, api, telegram

мне надо с телеграмм канала(https://t.me/battle_legendary) реализовать, чтобы при появлении нового сообщения, скрипт брал текст сообщения и доставал от туда только сам промокод. Я не понимаю, как это реализовать. Пробовал через Telethon, не получилось даже entity канала узнать, просто выдает ошибку, что не удалось найти такой, хотя я его получал через `client.get_entity("@battle_legendary")` и с -100 и без, ничего.

Вроде задача очень простая, просто возьми последнее сообщение и скопируй его, все, но я не понимаю.

Пробовал вынести через `client.iter_messages('-1001834701763', limit=1)`, но он меня тоже нафиг послал.

При этом после каждого подключения через API, меня выкидывает со всех устройств и приходится каждый раз входить в телеграмм аккаунт заново.

Буду очень благодарен, если вы подскажете решение данной задачи

Answer (score 0):

Для того, чтобы получать содержимое новых сообщений в Telegram канале, вам нужно использовать Telegram Bot API. После создания бота и получения токена, вы можете использовать метод `getUpdates` для получения списка обновлений (новых сообщений) в канале.

1. Создайте бота в Telegram и получите токен.
2. Добавьте бота в канал в качестве администратора.
3. Используйте следующий код для получения обновлений в канале и извлечения промокода из последнего сообщения:

```py
import requests

TOKEN = 'YOUR_BOT_TOKEN'
CHANNEL_NAME = 'battle_legendary'

def get_updates():
    url = f'https://api.telegram.org/bot{TOKEN}/getUpdates'
    response = requests.get(url)
    return response.json()

def extract_promocode(message):
    # здесь вы можете реализовать извлечение промокода из текста сообщения
    return promocode

updates = get_updates()['result']
if updates:
    last_message = updates[-1]['message']
    if last_message['chat']['title'] == CHANNEL_NAME:
        promocode = extract_promocode(last_message['text'])
        print(promocode)
```

В этом примере мы используем метод `getUpdates` для получения списка обновлений (новых сообщений), а затем извлекаем последнее сообщение в канале и извлекаем промокод из его текста.

При использовании Bot API вы не должны быть выкинуты со всех устройств при каждом подключении к аккаунту.

Надеюсь, это поможет вам решить задачу!

Comment: Проблема в том, что канал не мой и бота в качестве администратора, я туда добавить не могу

Comment: При этом, вот этот бот @junction_bot он все прекрасно делает и он копирует же как то последнее сообщение. Одно непонятно для меня, как